# Topology: Open, Closed Set and infinity norm

Tags: calculus, general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Since last week I've been learning a bit about Topology in Calculus and know the basic definitions of open, closed, norm, etc. Now I try to solve this question but I don't know how to. Its really really confusing and difficult to imagine...

> Let $(X,d) = (\mathbb{R^2}, d_\infty)$ and $M := [0, \infty) \times (0,\infty) \subset X.$ Prove:
>
> 1. $\quad A_1 := \left \{{(x, y) \in \ X : 0 \leq x < y}\right \}$ is open in $M$, but not in $X$
> 2. $\quad A_2 := \left \{{(x, y) \in \ X : 0 < y \leq x}\right \}$ is closed in $M$, but not in $X$

Can someone help me?

Thanks
Landau

Comment: Try first imagining how the open sets look like in $d_\infty$. How would a ball of radius $1$ look like ? It would be a square.

Comment: can see  whether $M$ is open in $X$ or not?

Comment: ahh ok, $d_2$ is the unit sphere and $d_\infty$ looks like a square. Seems like the unit sphere is approaching to the square for growing n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Believe that M be with the induced topology.
Remark that $U=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2;\, x<y\}$ is open in $X$ and too $F=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2;\, y\leq x\}$ is closed in X, with $U^c=F$. In fact, $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$, $f(x,y)=x-y$ is continuous, then look that $U=f^{-1}((-\infty,0))$ and $F=f^{-1}([0,+\infty))$.

Now, remark that $A_1=U\cap M$ and $A_2=F\cap M$. Thus $A_1$ is open in $M$ and $A_2$ is closed in $M$.

If $A_1$ is open in $X$, then exists a ball (or square) $B$ centered at $(0,1)\in A_1$ such that $B\subset A_1$. Thus, exists $(x,y)\in A_1$ with $x<0$, which is a contradiction with the definition of $A_1$. The case of $A_2$ note that $(1,0)\in cl(A_2)\setminus A_2$, then $A_2$ is not closed in $X$.

Comment: can you explain me why we have to look at $cl(A_2)\setminus A_2$ and why then $A_2$ is not closed in X? Is this because we look at ${0 \leq y < x}$ and if $(1,0) \in cl(A_2)\setminus A_2$ it can't be closed in X because of $0 \leq y < x$?